# Разработка WPF приложений под планшет

Tags: wpf, touch

Доброго времени!

Имеется ли у кого опыт разработки на WPF (вариант с Windows Store не интересует) под планшет?

Пробовал работать со стандартными контролами, но заметил "странное" поведение некоторых, например, ScrollViewer'а - при проматывании содержимого видны "подергивания". Кнопки реагируют на нажатия через раз и прочие прелести.

Comment: Странно. А воспроизводится на тривиальном приложении? Или может вы делаете что-то тяжёлое в UI-потоке, и не хватает мощности процессора? (Disclaimer: опыта с планшетом нет.)

Comment: @VladD, да, вопсроизводится. Так же обычный ComboBox раскрывается не всегда с первого раза. В плане "железа" все в порядке.

Comment: То есть на пустом приложении, с одним только главным окном? Если да, то может быть вы не вписываетесь в hardware requirements для WPF :-(

Comment: @VladD, единственные вменяемые требования нашел в таком виде: > 800MHz Processor; 512 MBytes RAM; DirectX 9 capable graphics adapter. В них я укладываюсь.

Comment: Странно. Если воспроизводится без code-behind, что-то не так. Тогда может надо пожаловаться прямо в Microsoft? Да, а может, у вас нет аппаратного ускорения графики? Как ведёт себя нагрузка на процессор?

Answer (score 3):

"Подергивания" это отклик системы на BoundaryFeedback event. Отключить можно, но не всегда работает (проверял на разных устройствах) - с чем связано так и не выяснил. [Вы можете найти похожий вопрос тут.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451873/windows-7-touch-screen-shrug)